# Not using threads but get wrong result with ArrayList and right with Vector

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

In a simple Java program for a school assignment where I didn't use any threads (unless Java somehow optimizes the code to use them). Why is it that when I do

```
java App < test.txt // correct result
java App < test.txt > ans.txt // 1 wrong result
```

Then I switch the use of ArrayList to Vector, and it works. I think the only difference is synchronization? If I dont use threads, why do I get different results? Also the trigger for wrong result seem to be just `> ans.txt`, output redirection? But earlier, I also noticed a few oddities where I got different results when I added some println vs none.

Why is this? I would expect to get the same result from ArrayList/Vector when I do not use threads? I used ArrayList as I thought, since I am not using threads, I can get away with ArrayList?

**UPDATE**

The code is https://gist.github.com/3720606. Just try:

```
java SchedulingDeliveries < Subtask1.txt // should give wrong result
```

Expected answer is Subtask1-ans.txt, can try diff ans.txt with that

Then try search and replace ArrayList to Vector, then try again. Should work

Comment: Can you be more specific on the difference? Can you post the relevant part of your code which does the output? I can hardly imagine that by adding an output redirection you get different results ...

Comment: -1 for omitting all relevant details.  Clean up the post and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Please post the code that handles input and output.

Comment: Why don't you use a `PriorityQueue` instead of your own max heap?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, Oh because the Lecturer wanted us to try doing our own. He designed the question such that priorities can change. Can PriorityQueue or some other data structure do that? If so I will be happy to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding ArrayMaxHeap implementation (answer by studying your code and comparing with what you think should be happending):

- What happens to the size of `list` when `dequeue()` is called?
- `dequeue` moves an element from the last position in the array to the "first" (not counting index 0), then calls `shiftDown(1)`.  What happens to the `queueIndex` of the element that was moved, if `shiftDown` doesn't end up swapping it with another element for some reason (maybe it's the last element left)?

Comment: Hmm yes, thanks for pointing out my mistake. However, it looks like I am not using dequeue anywhere in the code ... so this mistake should not affect the answer. I'll fix it tho